SSL configuration with Nginx with Django
I am trying to configure the SSL to the environment. The combination of technical stack nginx, Angular and Django. I downloaded the cert and placed into the server for the nginx and added the below configuration in the Django - settings.py for the SSL in the backend.
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

Added the below configuration in the nginx server block.
server {
 
    listen 8000 ssl;
   
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/servername.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/servername.key;
    ssl_password_file /etc/ssl/global.pass;
    server_name  localhost;
 
    underscores_in_headers on;
    client_max_body_size 2500M;
 
 
    location / {
 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
 
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
 
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
 
        proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
 
        proxy_pass https://backend;
 
          
    proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        
    
    proxy_ssl_password_file /etc/ssl/global.pass;
        
    }
 
}

Tried the few stackoverflow solutions, but nothing works.
I am getting the below error messge
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '
https://servername/login/'
from origin '
https://servername:4200'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Just want to get more clarity on the nginx configuration. Did I miss anything? I searched few answers but unable to get the solution.


The specific traceback is not at all related to SSL. Its the frontend app trying to access backend resources, without proper authorization.  You can use django-cors-headers to enable access.

Try adding allowed host and use django-cors-headers

Hi @Niko - Thanks for the response. django-cors-headers already exists. It was with version 3.1.1. So upgraded to 4.4.0 as per the documentation.  I added the CORS-ALLOW-ORIGINS with the server and DNS names, restarted the Django services. But the issue still exists. I attached the screenshot in the original post. Thanks again for your input..

Hi @AkramSheriff - I did. The issue still exists. Attached the error screenshot in the original post.

Please, beware of typos. Its CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [...] not ALLOW. If you correctly follow the documentation , its bound to work.

Hi @Niko - Thanks for the quick response. Sorry it's my typo while replying here. There is no typo in the server's settings.py file. Even I added this settings  -"CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True" and started the Django service, but no luck.
Anything else I am missing?
